# Change the color of arrows using Slick on Github pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Slick to add a carousel on my Github pages, but I have trouble setting the color of arrows. By default the arrows are white and since my background is white, I try to make the arrows visible and yellow by

```css
    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: yellow;
    }
```

I only get a [yellow arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJZkt.png), but what I expected is a [yellow circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxM8w.png) with a white arrow in it.

I don't know where went wrong. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: try to force the use with `.slick-prev::before, .slick-next::before { color: red !important; }`

Comment: you want your color to be white and your background-color to be yellow (I think)

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with the 'slick' font family not loading or being broken at some point.  What you're seeing is a fallback for when the 'slick' font family can't be loaded.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/51h1y90p/.  In the top slider, I've broken the font family rule and the odd arrows appear, but in the bottom one it works fine with the same rule for the yellow color.  Are you getting any 404 errors in your javascript or network consoles?

Comment: @JosephMarikle you are right about the 404 errors! I added woff and tff files to assets/fonts, and it worked out fine. Thank you a lot!.

Answer (score 4):

***Edit:*** I just saw the fiddle above. If you set the `font-family` to `initial!important` and add `color:yellow;` then your yellow background will work:

```
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
    font-family:initial!important;
    color:yellow; 
}
```

(or you could pick a  yellow [variant](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp))

[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/1ga39qpb/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Rachel, but when I deleted the fonts and added font-family as initial in my css, all I got is a single yellow arrow, and a bunch of error messages telling me fonts missing. In your fiddle if I remove the font-family the result is the same.

Comment: The point was to USE Font family initial... It reverts to the slick font !! Sigh..

Comment: you'll note that in the fiddle NO specific font family is set in the css in the fiddle.. only the slick files are used in the external resources (which is where their font-family is set).. so if you set the font-family to initial and ADD !important before the colon (this is IMPORTANT) then it will work..

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen. Works for me!  Might want to add the full CSS from your fiddle to the answer.  It was the extra line that did it for me:  `.adjusted .slick-arrow:before {font-family:initial!iimportant; color:yellow;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can Add this css to get the same view that shown in the example doc of react slick

[image: Demo image:]

```
  .slick-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243) !important;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  
  .slick-prev {
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243) !important;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  

  .slick-prev:before,
  .slick-next:before {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
```